# System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException when Parameter count can be dynamic

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, delegates, invoke

All methods in the "ProbabilitiesTheory" class accept dynamic count of parameters - it means that there can be put as many parameters as one wants. But .NET still says "System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException" when invoking a method, that has "params" keyword in its parameters.

Here's the code:

```
internal static class ProbabilitiesTheory
{
    static public double GetMediumValue(params double[] integers)
    { }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodInfo[] methods = Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication1.ProbabilitiesTheory").GetMethods();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write the name of the method\n");
            string NameOfMethod = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Write the parameters of the method using the following format: 
            parameter1;parameter2;parameter3;parameterN\n");
            string ParametersOfMethod = Console.ReadLine();

            foreach (var i in methods)
            {
                if (i.Name == NameOfMethod)
                {
                    object[] @parameters = (from t in ParametersOfMethod.Split(';') where t != "" select (object)Convert.ToDouble(t)).ToArray();

                    i.Invoke(null, @parameters); // Exception HERE
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("______");
        }
    }
}
```

It is absolutely ok with LINQ expression there, i get what i need to get: object[] containing dynamic amount of double values.

How do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as reflection is concerned, a `params array` is just an array with a fancy syntactical sugar. You could solve the immediate problem for most of your methods by adjusting your code like so:

```
double[] @parameters = (from t in ParametersOfMethod.Split(';') where t != "" select Convert.ToDouble(t)).ToArray();

i.Invoke(null, new[] { @parameters});
```

The gist of this is that a `params array` is just a single parameter at run-time, and the ability to add a variable amount of values to it is just a nicety done by the compiler.

You can confirm this with a snippet like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var parameterCount = typeof(Test).GetMethod("Foo").GetParameters().Count();
    Console.WriteLine(parameterCount); // Output: 2
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static class Test 
{
    public static void Foo(double x, params double[] y) 
    {}
}
```

If you need to invoke a function that uses a `params array` with user provided values when the `params array` is not the only parameter, you're going to need to get the method parameter count and work out where the array actually starts, then wrap things accordingly.